# How do I export results of a LogBlock query to a text file?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition-server

I'd like to export results of a LogBlock query to a textfile. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: By LogBlock query you mean? Im asking this because essentially LogBlock is just a SQL Database and if it means what I think you mean, you are basically asking how to export SQL query results to a text file.

Comment: Ideally in LogBlock; I was hoping I wouldn't have to learn SQL to achieve this, but that's Plan B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the commands reference at LogBlock's GitHub,

> `/lb writelogfile <params>`
>
> Writes result of query using params specified to a log file located at `/plugins/LogBlock/log/*.log` where * is replaced with a
> friendly title. Additionally prints location of file to the user.

The referenced link is as follows

https://github.com/LogBlock/LogBlock/wiki/Commands

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much, @DarkDestry---I'm not sure how I missed this before.